# SQL case statement not executing 'else'

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, case

I am on Oracle 12.1.0.2.0
I have a query that I wrote utilizing a CASE statement. I have 2 "WHEN" statements and one "ELSE" statement. The query is working as expected except for the "ELSE" statement. I get no syntax errors it just not hitting the "ELSE" case when it should, and instead returns nothing.

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN COUNT(COLUMN_A) = 1
    THEN 'PASS'
WHEN COUNT(COLUMN_A) > 1
    THEN 'FAIL'
ELSE 'DOES NOT EXIST'
END AS TEST,
SCH.COLUMN_A
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_A SCH
WHERE SCH.COLUMN_A = 'NA'
GROUP BY COLUMN_A
```

When I run this query (which in my understanding is the else case) then it returns 0 as it should:

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_A) < 1
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_A SCH
WHERE SCH.COLUMN_A = 'NA'
```

If you need to provide table structure, let me know but it is fairly straightforward.

What am I doing wrong? Why, when the query returns 0, is the else statement not returning "DOES NOT EXIST"? I have a feeling it is something simple but I am stuck and could use some help. I appreciate it.

Comment: So your second query returns 0 as the count? It is getting a count for column_a where the number is less than 1. Your first when is equal to 1, your second is greater than 1, your else is anything less than 1 effectively which you said in your second query returns 0. It sounds to me like your else clause is working?

Comment: So the input is 0... 1 returns 'PASS', >1 returns 'FAIL', which leaves the ELSE set <=0 (which includes 0) & returns 'DOES NOT EXIST'. It is working as designed. I think we must be missing something here.

Comment: Add `CREATE TABLE` statement and `INSERT` statements with data that illustrates the problem

Comment: Remove the GROUP BY from the first quert

Comment: the 2nd query does return 0. My understanding is that if that is the case, then the first query should return "DOES NOT EXIST" but instead it returns nothing

Answer (score 2):

You used this predicate: `COLUMN_A = 'NA'`

The result of `COUNT(COLUMN_A)` can be 0 only if you have 0 rows where `COLUMN_A = 'NA'` (as nulls are excluded because of the predicate). If you have 0 rows, the `CASE` statement is not evaluated at all, and the above query returns no result.

You need a query that returns result even if no rows match your predicate. E.g:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN C = 1
      THEN 'PASS'
    WHEN C > 1
      THEN 'FAIL'
    ELSE 'DOES NOT EXIST',
    'NA'
FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS C
  FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_A SCH
  WHERE SCH.COLUMN_A = 'NA'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is NO records with COLUMN_A = 'NA' there will be NO records in output.

Use something like

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN COUNT(SCH.COLUMN_A) = 1
    THEN 'PASS'
WHEN COUNT(SCH.COLUMN_A) > 1
    THEN 'FAIL'
ELSE 'DOES NOT EXIST'
END AS TEST,
SCH.COLUMN_A
FROM (SELECT 'NA' COLUMN_A) dummy
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE_A SCH ON SCH.COLUMN_A = dummy.COLUMN_A
/* GROUP BY SCH.COLUMN_A */
```